# python 3.8 tkinter calling new window from method creates a blank window

Tags: python, tkinter, new-window, createwindow

I am trying to call a new window by pushing the button of an existing window. The original window should close when the new window is being created. When I push the button the new window will show up as expected but additionally a blank window will appear. Using `tk.Tk()` or `tk.Toplevel()` will lead to the same result.

Later in the program I want to destroy the created window again. When using `tk.Tk()` closing the blank window by mouse will create an error "application has been destroyed" when the `destroy()` method gets applicated to the new window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Hauptmenü")

    Menue = MainMenue(root)
    Menue.pack()

    root.mainloop()


class MainMenue(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button_rennen = tk.Button(self, text="New Window", width=20, command=self.call_bet)
        self.button_rennen.pack()

    def call_bet(self):
        self.destroy()
        root2 = tk.Tk()
        Bet = BetFrame(root2)
        Bet.pack()



class BetFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button = tk.Button(text="Wette platzieren",
                           command=self.question)

        self.button.pack()


    def question(self):
        dialog = tk.messagebox.askokcancel(message="Destroy Window?")

        if dialog is True:
            self.destroy()


main()
```

I am creating a new class for every new window since the original program should return some variables.
I know that there are already many questions to this topic but for me none of these seemed quite to fit and helped to find the solution for my problem. I am grateful for any help!

Comment: Instead of `self.destroy(); root2 = tk.Tk(); Bet = BetFrame(root2); Bet.pack()` use `Bet = BetFrame(self.master); Bet.pack(); self.destroy()`

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem with the blank window. Now the ```destroy()``` function inside the ```question()``` method is not closing anything. How can I fix that?

Comment: You need to pass `self` when creating the button in your `BetFrame`. I will write a proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class MainMenue(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button_rennen = tk.Button(self, text="New Window", width=20,
                                       command=self.call_bet)
        self.button_rennen.pack()

    def call_bet(self):
        # `self.master` is the window
        Bet = BetFrame(self.master)
        Bet.pack()
        self.destroy()


class BetFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # You need to tell the button that its master should be this BetFrame
        # If you don't it will assume you mean the window so
        # `self.destroy()` isn't going to destroy the button.
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Wette platzieren", command=self.question)
        self.button.pack()

    def question(self):
        dialog = tk.messagebox.askokcancel(message="Destroy Window?")

        if dialog is True:
            self.destroy()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()

    Menue = MainMenue(root)
    Menue.pack()

    root.mainloop()


main()
```

Your code is great but it was 2 mistakes:

- Instead of creating a new window is it better to reuse the old one.
- When you create your button in your `BetFrame` class, you don't pass anything for the master argument (the first argument). That is why the button isn't destroyed when you destroy the `BetFrame` object using `self.destroy()`

Comment: Thank you so much. That was really helpful!